# Fly.io - Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error rendering push status stream: received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: next.js, fly

I deployed my nextjs app on fly.io. I could have deployed it before. but I can not deploy it now. what is going on? Someone could help me out. I will really appreciate it.

`fly deploy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a very weird case. I changed the region like my region is `primary_region = "sin"`. I changed `primary_region = "hkg"` and then I changed back my region and I can deploy :xD.